# Errores al instalar el npm para usar Vue.js en laravel 5.5.44

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, npm

Buenas Amigos esta Vez estoy por aca xq me encuentro con un pequeño problema que de pronto muchos me podrian dar una mano...el asunto es el siguien:

al momento de ejecutar en la linea de comando: `npm run dev` me arroja los siguientes Errores;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he visto en este [enlace-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032999/laravel-5-5-vue-js-2-x-project-not-working-on-npm-run-dev) y en este otro [enlace-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562496/gulp-error-internal-child-process-js298-throw-errnoexceptionerr-spawn-err) algunos comandos de Ayuda, mas sin embargo no he podido solventar los Errores.

Agradecido!! de Antemano por su Ayuda, que verdaderamente me seria muy Oportuna!

Comment: ¿Estás usando Windows? Si es así, ¿Has probado desde CMD o Powershell?

Comment: Correcto si estoy usando windows, estuve intentando darle permisologia segun los enlaces referenciales que estuve viendo, pero no me permite cambiarle los permisos con (chmod -R u+x) ò (chmod -R 765), aparte de que si estoy en windows no deberia tener problemas de permisos...hasta los momentos sigo sin solventar el Error...Ahora bien contestando tu 2da pregunta, ps estoy usando la terminal que me facilita Git la cual es "Git Bash" la cual es como la terminal de linux, tal como la aprecias en la imagen, sin embargo la de CMD no la he usado...Gracias!